# How to improve my AMPL SP model with more dimensions

Tags: for-loop, matrix, ampl, stochastic

I have a problem with AMPL to do a stochastic programming,

currently I have three scenarios and assign probabilities before each solution.

```
for { t in 1..SIZE-1 by 2} {

    let Demand := DemandSeq[t];
    let Resources := ResourcesSeq[t];

    # change probability of each stage
    if StateSequence[t] = 1 # N
        then {
            let P[1]:= 0.7;
            let P[2]:= 0.2;
            let P[3]:= 0.1;
        }
    else if StateSequence[t] = 2 # A
        then {
            let P[1]:= 0.6;
            let P[2]:= 0.3;
            let P[3]:= 0.1;
        }
    else if StateSequence[t] = 3 # M
        then {
            let P[1]:= 0.5;
            let P[2]:= 0.4;
            let P[3]:= 0.1;
        };
  solve;
  ...
}
```

Now what if I change this three scenarios problem into a 10 scenarios problem. I already have a 10*10 probability matrix, but I don't know how to assign prob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I replied on the [AMPL Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ampl/GTTe-izhp7k/zREbHgcNmZoJ), you can define a two-dimensional parameter to store probabilities:

```
param Probs{1..10, 1..10};
```

define it in the data in a compact form (or read from a database or a spreadsheet), for example:

```
data;
param Probs :
   1   2   3   ...  10 :=
1 0.1 0.2 0.05 ... 0.1
...
```

and use an iterated form of `let` to assign the data to P:

```
let {i in 1..10} P[i] := Prob[StateSequence[t], i];
```